# Calculations with Safemath and now

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to make time calculations using openzeppelins Safemath library and the `now` keyword?

```
contract MyContract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint dayInSec = 86400;

    function calc() public returns(uint) {
        return now.add(dayInSec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why do you think it's not? `now` is just a short form of `block.timestamp` which is a uint256.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/cheatsheet.html?highlight=timestamp#global-variables